# replacing \n with new line

Tags: php, regex

I have a string consisting of text that can contain multiple `\` and `n`.

In php, with preg_replace, I want to replace `\n` with `[NewLine]` ONLY where needed. By saying replacing `\n` i mean replacing the characters backslash-n (`\` and `n`).

I browsed similar questions but didn't find one to handle the case of `\\n` which should not be replaced with new line.

For example, the string `hello\nworld` should be `hello[NewLine]world`,

and the string `hello\\nworld` should be `hello\nworld`.

Meaning :

```php
<?php
$source1 = <<<'EOD'
\n
EOD;

$source2 = <<<'EOD'
\\n
EOD;

$source3 = <<<'EOD'
\\\n
EOD;
//$source4 with 4 backslaskes , 5 with 5 etc.


//preg_replace `$source1` so it ends up as `[NewLine]`
//preg_replace `$source2` to `\\n`
//preg_replace `$source3` to `\\[NewLine]`
//etc
//....
//even number of consecutive \ followed by n means no [NewLine]
//odd number of consecutive \ followed by n means new [NewLine]
```

I had a wrong replacement code

```php
$a = preg_replace('{([^{\\\}])\\\n}', "$1\n", $string); 
//work as expected when $string is "first-line\\nsecond-line";
//doesn't work as expected when $string is "first-line\\\nsecond-line";
```

Anyone knows what needs to be done in a regular expression to have this working ?

Comment: What's wrong with `str_replace("\n", "[NewLine]")`?

Comment: @knittl with that replace,  `hello\\nworld` would be `hello\[NewLine]world` but i need it as `hello\nworld`

Comment: Try `str_replace('\\\\', '\\', preg_replace('~(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\K\\\\n~', '\n', $text));`

Comment: Does https://3v4l.org/urhuI solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip parts of the string using the *backtracking control verb* `(*SKIP)`:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\\\\.(*SKIP)(?<=n)~', "\n", $source);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/QoG8m)

`(*SKIP)` skips positions of the string already reached by the subpattern before it when the subpattern after it fails.
`(?<=n)` is a lookbehind assertion and means *preceded by n*. When it fails, the regex engine jumps after the escaped character position (the position defined by `(*SKIP)`) for a new attempt, instead of testing the next position (the position after the backslash).

---

You can also do the same using `strtr`:

```
$result = strtr($source, ['\\\\' => '\\\\', '\\n' => "\n"]);
```

*(since there's a replacement defined for two consecutive backslashes, the second backslash can't be used for an eventual following `n`.)*

Answer (score 1):

You need to match either pairs of backslashes `\\` or the pair `\n`. By specifying a callback you can check if replacing it is required and if not, simply return the matched characters verbatim:

```php
<?php

$inputs = [
    "\n is [NewLine]",
    "\\n is \n",
    "\\\n is \[NewLine]",
    "\n and \\n and \\\n and \\\\n"
];

$nl = function($matches) {
    return $matches[0] == "\n" ? "[NewLine]" : $matches[0];
};

print_r(preg_replace_callback("/\\\\|\\n/", $nl, $inputs));
```

By putting `\\` first in the regex alternation, it will be consumed first and only if there's an odd number of backslashes, the `\n` will be matched.

(Make sure you escape the backslashes in the regex pattern!)

Output for that last sample input: `[NewLine] and \n and \[NewLine] and \\n`

---

If your input contains a literal backslash character and `n` (0x5c 0x6e) instead of the newline character (0x0a) – so your input is really `\\n` and not `\n` – you need to add one additional level of escaping. The regular expression becomes `/\\\\\\\\|\\\\n/` and the callback must check for `"\\n"`

Comment: There is no new line in the input, only backslashes and the n character. `$input1 = "\\n";// must end up as [NewLine]` while `$input2 = "\\\\n"; ////must end up as the literal \n` and finally `$input3 = "\\\\\\n";//must be end up as \[NewLine]`

Comment: @aconrad: do I understand this correctly, `\n` in your sample input is not a newline, but a literal backslash followed by the n character? In that case, you need to escape once more in the pattern (and replace callback)

Comment: @knittle, idd, there are no new lines in the input string just backslashes and n's

Answer (score -1):

Found a easier solution. Like knittl said, pair matching `\` was the key, and regxp no really needed.

```php
strtr($input, ['\\\\' => '\\','\\n' => "[NL]"]);
```

Tested at https://3v4l.org/5tebZ

```php
$um = [
        '\\\\' => '\\',
        '\\n' => "[NL]",
    ];

$inputs = [];
for ($i=1;$i<=14;$i++) {
   $inputs[] = ''.str_repeat("\\", $i)."n";
}

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    $results[] = strtr($input, $um);
}

foreach ($inputs as $key=>$value)
{
    echo str_pad($value, 15, ' ',STR_PAD_LEFT)." =======> ".$results[$key]."\n";
}
```

Output

```
             \n =======> [NL]
            \\n =======> \n
           \\\n =======> \[NL]
          \\\\n =======> \\n
         \\\\\n =======> \\[NL]
        \\\\\\n =======> \\\n
       \\\\\\\n =======> \\\[NL]
      \\\\\\\\n =======> \\\\n
     \\\\\\\\\n =======> \\\\[NL]
    \\\\\\\\\\n =======> \\\\\n
   \\\\\\\\\\\n =======> \\\\\[NL]
  \\\\\\\\\\\\n =======> \\\\\\n
 \\\\\\\\\\\\\n =======> \\\\\\[NL]
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n =======> \\\\\\\n
```